# FTP Client - Overwrite a folder (removing orphaned files)

Tags: windows, windows-10, ftp

**Is it possible to overwrite an entire folder
via some FTP client?**

I have a situation like this:

```
local/temp/ttt               |          remote/temp/ttt
bbb.txt                      |          aaa.txt
                             |
```

and I want to end up like this:

```
local/temp/ttt               |          remote/temp/ttt
bbb.txt                      |          bbb.txt
```

meaning I want to copy the folder `ttt` from `/local/temp` to `/remote/temp`

and that the folder `ttt` in remote will be completely overwritten by `ttt` folder

from `/local/temp`

I tried that with this ftp clients:  FileZilla, Cyberduck, WinSCP, WS_FTP.

And no luck. They all just `merge` the folders and I end up like this:

```
local/temp/ttt               |          remote/temp/ttt
bbb.txt                      |          aaa.txt
                             |          bbb.txt
```

**Is there any possibility to do that by any FTP client?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imo, there's nothing like *"overwriting a folder"*, in general. And definitely not in FTP.

What you want to achieve is called *directory/folder synchronization*.

Some FTP clients do support synchronizing local and remote folders.

- WinSCP does:
  https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_synchronize
  You will want to enable *Delete files* option to get rid of obsolete files (`aaa.txt` in your example).
- Cyberduck too:
  https://docs.cyberduck.io/cyberduck/sync/
  Though it seems it does not support deleting obsolete files, so it's probably not useful for your purposes.
- FileZilla imo does not. I do not know about WS_FTP.

Comment: IIRC, macOS overwrites, i.e. deletes the contents of, a folder if you copy another folder with the same name into the same parent folder. ICBW.